# How to convert a div to input and then the input into div (onclick)

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, onclick

I have 5 names and on clicking them, they convert to an input with a save button. On clicking save, the input and save disappear and the old div should show up with the update input value. I am not able to update the old div with the input value. Please help.

> Now I want to click on save and get the original div back in it's place with the updated input value. I am almost at the end but stuck.

**Initially it looks like this:**

[image: 1]

**On clicking the div, it looks like this:**

[image: 2]

> Please help and give a detailed explanation so that I can understand how to go about it from the next time.

**Parent Component**

```
  state = {
    showNames : false,
    userNames: [],
    value: []
  }

  componentDidMount = () => {
    const {names} = this.props;
    const updatedNames = names.map((name) => ({...name, ...{isEditable: false}})); 
    this.setState({
      userNames: updatedNames
    })
  }

 inputNamesHandler = (namesIndex) => {
    const {userNames} = this.state;
    const updatedUserNameDetails = [...userNames];
    updatedUserNameDetails[namesIndex].isEditable = true;
    this.setState({userNames: updatedUserNameDetails})
  }

  saveButton = (inputValue, index) => {
    alert(inputValue + ' was clicked');
    alert(inputValue);
    alert(index);  
  }

  render() {
      return <div>
          <h1>Hello</h1>
          <div>
              {this.state.userNames.map((nameDetails, index) => {
                  if(nameDetails.isEditable) {
                    return (<div><TextArea clicked={(name) => this.saveButton(name, index)}/></div>);
                  } else {
                    return <div onClick={() => this.inputNamesHandler(index)} style={styles.namesContainer}>
                    <div style={styles.firstMargin}><FirstName firstName={nameDetails.firstName}></FirstName></div>
                    <div><LastName lastName={nameDetails.lastName}></LastName></div>
                    </div>
                  }
              })}        
          </div> 
          </div>     
    }
}
```

**Child Component**

```
export default class TextArea extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {value:''}

        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        // this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    handleChange(event) {
        this.setState({value: event.target.value});
    }

    render() {
        console.log('Textarea was rendered')
        return (
            <div>
                <div style={styles.inputContainer}>
                <input type="text" style={styles.textField} value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange}></input>
                <button type="submit" style={styles.saveButton} onClick={() => this.props.clicked(this.state.value)}>Save</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        )

    }
}
```

The names are saved in another component which are being accessed using props.

Comment: So you want onClick edit and once you save update, right?

Comment: @Vishal Mishra can you share your code in sandbox and tell how many inputs/div's are there?

Comment: @DhavalJardosh Yes that is exactly what I want

Answer (score 4):

This is something that you're expecting.

There is a better way of doing this, but this is just a brute force way.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    one: { firstName: "Player", lastName: "One" },
    two: { firstName: "Two", lastName: "Player" },
    three: { firstName: "Three", lastName: "Player" },
    four: { firstName: "Four", lastName: "Player" },
    five: { firstName: "Five", lastName: "Player" }
  };

  oneUpdate = updatedValue => {
    this.setState({
      one: {
        firstName: updatedValue.firstName,
        lastName: updatedValue.lastName
      }
    });
  };

  twoUpdate = updatedValue => {
    this.setState({
      two: {
        firstName: updatedValue.firstName,
        lastName: updatedValue.lastName
      }
    });
  };

  threeUpdate = updatedValue => {
    this.setState({
      three: {
        firstName: updatedValue.firstName,
        lastName: updatedValue.lastName
      }
    });
  };

  fourUpdate = updatedValue => {
    this.setState({
      four: {
        firstName: updatedValue.firstName,
        lastName: updatedValue.lastName
      }
    });
  };

  fiveUpdate = updatedValue => {
    this.setState({
      five: {
        firstName: updatedValue.firstName,
        lastName: updatedValue.lastName
      }
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { one, two, three, four, five } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <PlayerBlock name={one} update={this.oneUpdate} />
        <PlayerBlock name={two} update={this.twoUpdate} />
        <PlayerBlock name={three} update={this.threeUpdate} />
        <PlayerBlock name={four} update={this.fourUpdate} />
        <PlayerBlock name={five} update={this.fiveUpdate} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class PlayerBlock extends React.Component {
  state = {
    editMode: false,
    userName: {},
    firstName: "",
    lastName: ""
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    // this.setState({userName:this.props.name});
    this.setState({
      firstName: this.props.name.firstName
    });
    this.setState({
      lastName: this.props.name.lastName
    });
  }

  sendData = () => {
    this.props.update({
      firstName: this.state.firstName,
      lastName: this.state.lastName
    });
    this.setState({ editMode: false });
  };

  render() {
    var { editMode } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.editMode ? (
          <div>
            <input
              value={this.state.firstName}
              onChange={e => this.setState({ firstName: e.target.value })}
            />
            <input
              value={this.state.lastName}
              onChange={e => this.setState({ lastName: e.target.value })}
            />
            <button onClick={() => this.sendData()}>Save</button>
          </div>
        ) : (
          <div onClick={() => this.setState({ editMode: true })}>
            {this.props.name.firstName} {this.props.name.lastName}
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason your input isn't converting back to div is because you didn't change the "isEditable" key of the input to "false" in the "saveButton" function. That's why it keeps rendering the input because isEditable is true.